# How do i use inversed tan in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate an angle of a triangle by using the `tan^-1` function. On my calculator I can do this:

`tan^-1(3/4)` // 3 and 4 are triangle side lengths

And it outputs 36 degrees. What is the alternative to this function in JavaScript? I tried `Math.tan(3/4)`, `Math.atan(3/4)` and all of the other *tan* functions I saw in the list, but none of them outputs the result in degrees I need (36).
Thank you.

Comment: javascript works in radians

Comment: By the way it should be 36.8698976, not 36. Math.atan(3/4) * 180 / Math.PI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no build in function for that, since `1 radian = 180/pi degrees` you can do the following using **[`Math.atan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan)** and **[`Math.PI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI)**

```js
var degree = Math.atan(3 / 4) * (180 / Math.PI);

document.write(degree);
```